# How can I track the changes an installer makes?

Tags: macos, installer

I'm trying to track the changes of an installer/patcher, is there a way to track changes the installer/patcher makes and where all its files are placed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Standard OS X Installer packages can easily be viewed. One tool for this is [Suspicious Package](http://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/), a QuickLook plugin that shows files and scripts contained in the Installer package.

---

While installing, you can monitor file system accesses using tools like `opensnoop` or `fs_usage` (both command line utilities).

Answer (score 5):

You can show the files that would be copied by an installer by pressing command-I:

[image]

Or with lsbom:

```
$ lsbom ~/Desktop/KeyRemap4MacBook.pkg/Contents/Archive.bom
.   40755   501/20
./Library   40755   0/0
./Library/LaunchAgents  40755   0/0
./Library/LaunchAgents/org.pqrs.KeyRemap4MacBook.server.plist   100644  0/0 485 2125025754
...
```

Comment: Thanks, these are great too, but how exactly does the cmd-I work, it tried that one and it didn't seem to show anything but well, the information about the installer. I'm assuming it only works on apple package installers? I'm using a custom game installer BTW. But still thanks I got what I needed.

Comment: @MPX There's a standard format for OS X installers, `pkg`, created by Apple's developer tools and comparable with MSI on Windows. If the developer's roll their own solution, you're on your own, having to use file system monitoring and similar workarounds.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I thought! Thanks for the help.