# Creating a combined Mac package installer?

Tags: macos, printing, installer

I work in a university library.  We offer wireless printing services to our students using Pharos Print Server, and we have [handy installers](http://library.und.edu/computing/wireless-printing.php) for the Windows print drivers.

There are Mac drivers available, but the Mac [installation process](http://und.edu/tech-support/students/uniprint-mac-instructions.cfm) is incredibly painful.  It requires downloading, installing, and configuring 2 different programs, followed by manually defining a new printer with some decidedly non-intuitive settings.  Overall there are 43 steps if you know EXACTLY what you're doing.

I'd like to create combined installer program that would let our Mac users download a single file, run it, and get everything set up automatically without having to mess around with advanced printer settings.  On Windows, I would use [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) for this.  Is there an equivalent program I could use on Mac?

EDIT:

The Pharos print system requires two programs to be installed in order to function:

1. Pharos Notify, which monitors print requests (I think)
2. Pharos Popup, which pops up a dialog asking the user to assign a name and password to each print job handled by Pharos.

The DMG files for those two programs contained .pkg files.  I used `installer` to run those in silent mode, then tried copying a printer app folder into ~/Library/Printers:

```
sudo -S installer -verbose -pkg Notify.pkg -target /
sudo -S installer -verbose -pkg Popup.pkg -target /
cp -r ./printers/ ~/Library/Printers/
```

The two packages work fine when installed in this manner, but the system doesn't recognize the printer settings.

In order to create the printer settings, I did the setup for a printer via the System Preferences UI, then copied the resulting .app folder out of ~/Library/Printers to a "printers" directory in the same place as the .pkg files.  But copying it back into the ~/Library/Printers folder does not seem to make OSX recognize the printer.  So I guess the problem there is that I don't know how to create or deploy preconfigured printer settings on Mac.

Comment: Have you tried simply providing a preconfigured printer package (in `~/Library/Printers`) for download, one for each of the queues?

Comment: Also, standard OS X installer packages (such as the one for Popup and Notify) can easily be [viewed](http://superuser.com/questions/465508/how-can-i-track-the-changes-an-installer-makes/465526#465526), and probably with little effort, be merged into a single setup package. Using the command-line tool `installer`, you can probably install them silently as well.

Comment: No, I haven't tried either of those things -- I'll look into them and report back.  Thanks.

Comment: @DanielBeck Okay, made some progress.  See updated question.

Comment: Just a wild guess (no idea if a printer application is sufficiently self-contained), have you opened the printer application at least once after installation?

Comment: I've tried quitting and restarting both the Print & Scan system preferences section and TextEdit, which I've been using for testing.  Neither one lists any printer at all, even though I can see the .app folder for the printer in ~/Library/Printers.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. It's an application showing the printing queue and giving access to printer maintenance operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the solution was to use [lpadmin](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man8/lpadmin.8.html) command to configure a new printer.  My finished script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Installing Pharos Notify ..."
installer -verbose -pkg Notify.pkg -target /

echo "Installing Pharos Popup ..."
installer -verbose -pkg Popup.pkg -target /

echo "Configuring black and white printer ..."
lpadmin -p CFL_Black_and_White -L "Chester Fritz Library, room 230, by reference desk." -E -v popup://uniprint.und.nodak.edu/CFL230_BW_MAC_Q -P ./CFL_Black_and_White.ppd

echo "Configuring color printer ..."
lpadmin -p CFL_Color -L "Chester Fritz Library, room 230, by circulation desk." -E -v popup://uniprint.und.nodak.edu/CFL%20Color%20Q -P /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/HP\ Color\ LaserJet\ 4700.gz

echo "Installation complete!"
```

Then, I used [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) to make a friendly click-to-run application out of the script, being sure to click the checkbox that runs the whole script using admin permissions after prompting the user for their password.  And I made a DMG for distribution purposes.  The end result is a comparatively simple installer for the library's printers.

There are two caveats:

1. Because neither Popup, Notify, nor the script itself have been approved by Apple, they will *not* run on OSX 10.8 or later unless the user [loosens their system security settings](http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/27/app-cant-be-opened-because-it-is-from-an-unidentified-developer/).
2. For reasons that I haven't nailed down yet, the color printer doesn't always get set up. I suspect the PPD file isn't included by default in all Mac installations.

Hope this helps someone.